# Javascript quick question: How to edit textarea properties when user clicks away

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

EDIT: onblur worked! Thanks!! :D

A good example of this is facebook.com. When you click on the comment box the textarea size increases and the text "Write a comment" is removed. That I already know how to do.

The problem that arises for me is when a user (me) clicks away from that container div, the textarea goes back to the original settings.

What javascript method am I looking for?

Comment: Have you tried the `onblur` function?

Comment: You should mark a right answer!

Comment: I wanted to but I had to wait 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `blur` method.

Here is an example (using jQuery):

http://jsfiddle.net/c747a/

And one without jQuery (although I would use jQuery):

http://jsfiddle.net/kxW3G/